# What do you call these long rectangular tables you usually find at McDonald's?

Tags: single-word-requests

[image]

What do you call these type of tables? Bar table? Joined table?

Comment: It's a "long rectangular table".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A long narrow dining table is known as a [*Refectory Table*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&source=hp&q=define+refectory+table&oq=define+refectory+table).

Traditionally these are made of hardwood but the term still applies to modern tables like your picture.

The term comes from the *Refectory* in a monastery where monks would sit on benches along the long side of the table to eat.  Such tables are still in use in school dining rooms.

Answer (score 1):

I call just table.
I think Bar should be higher than that and can sit just one side.

like this [image]